# Django ORM inside model label - speed

Tags: django, django-models

Using Django 1.11 and python 2.7,
I have a heavy Django admin App with the code below:

```
    # same as __str__ in python 3
    def __unicode__(self):
    redirected = "REDIRECTED-" if self.is_redirected else ""
    return u'[{}{}] {}'.format(redirected, self.typecode, self.headline)


    @property
    def is_redirected(self):
        return OtherModel.objects.filter(old_path=self.url).exists()
```

The problem is since the model label (the name that defaults as an output when printing the object) is used in a lot of places in the admin template this calls the ORM each time which drains  ~200ms each time and it totals 8 times to ~2 seconds per page and I would like to speed that up and reduce calls.

The obvious answer is cache but calling our cache also takes time since its on a different server so instead of getting 8 SQL calls I'll get 8 outside requests which is another thing I want to avoid.

I will not elaborate but I need everything to stay inside the **unicode** function.

Answer (score 1):

You can likely make use of the [`Exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) annotation.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Exists

class NewModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(NewModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        old_model = OldModel.objects.filter(old_path=OuterRef('url'))
        return queryset.annotate(
            has_old_model=Exists(old_model),
        )


class NewModel(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def is_redirected(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'has_old_model'):
            return self.has_old_model
        # Fall back to previous method if you're worried
        # you don't have all paths covered.
        return OtherModel.objects.filter(old_path=self.url).exists()
```